# Passing id to GET API url in Angular

Tags: angularjs, api, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass `ID` which I get from GET API to another GET API url which will be required in another state.

I have response from a GET API

```
[{
"ID" : 1,
"Name":"XYZ"
}]
```

I used Bootstrap cards in View , where I am generating above info in ng-repeat. On clicking in a particular  card which will redirect to other state with the information of coming from another API by passing ID of that particular card. 
Ex: `http://url/1`. This url will be GET as well .

I am new in this .How can I achieve this ? I have gone through *$stateparams* but really didn't get it.

Comment: not understand your requirement

Comment: @SangramBadi I want to pass the ID which I have mentioned in my json response, to another API endpoint which is in another state.

Answer (score 0):

will attempt to help you out.

I am amusing you are using ui-router, In which case your state definition should be as follows

```
{
  name: 'root',
  url: '/:id',
  controller:'rootController',
  resolve: {
    // info then can be injected into 'rootController'
    // $stateParams helps you access the :id property in the url
    info: ['$stateParams',function($stateParams) {
      // you make the second api call here. 
      return api.getInfo($stateParams.id);
    }]
  }
}
```

The takeaway form this is

1. :id in the url can be accessed via $stateParams service.
2. the resolve object literal allows you to make API call before the state controller is loaded and inject the results of the API call into said controller.

Hope this points you in the right direction, Cheers!

Comment: As you have mentioned in the first point. I don't want my ID to be in page url . It will be in an API endpoint when the page will get load.

Comment: I am not following this reqirement: "On clicking in a particular card which will redirect to other state with the information of coming from another AP" . Isn't what i described above the other state to which you redirect.

Comment: I am able to redirect to another page upon clicking. But I want particular information of that card which I am passing to be also get redirect so that `ID` which is in the information of the card will be the endpoint of another `GET` call in the next page. I think I am clear.

Comment: In which case you're link should be something like this <a ui-sref="otherState({ id: <ID> })">link</a>. Then pick up the id from the URL of the other state and make the required API call.

Comment: when user clicks on a card redirect  to a url: **info/1** where 1 is the id and **info** is the route/state , do this using **ui-sref**. Capture the id from the redirected url using **$stateParams** and used the captured id to make the necessary api calls. Hope this helps, i cant be more clear than this.

Comment: I am not passing any ID to the url of other state. I need the ID on API endpoint. And I think  API call is like this in the state. `info: function($http){
       return $http({method: 'GET' , url: 'url'})
       .then (function (data){
        return data.data;
        });
      },`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171975/discussion-between-whoami-and-jonathan-dsouza).